# Extract all the rows with a search value in a CSV file

Tags: java, csv

I'm at the end of my wits with this one. I'm trying to print all rows in a CVS file that has a specific value. So the code searches through row by row and prints all the values of the rows with the specific search value. This is what I have at this point

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String filename = "bos-2016-reg-csv-tables.csv";
        String searchValue = "LC0601_01";

        File file = new File(filename);
        try{
            Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
            inputStream.nextLine();      // ignore the first line

            while(inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
                String data = inputStream.nextLine();
            String[] value = data.split(",");
            if(searchValue.equals(value)){
               // TODO
            }

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: so what's the problem/question?

Comment: I can't figure out how to print all the rows that contains the search value

Comment: print to console output..? thats what `System.out.println(e);` do..

Answer (score 2):

Well,  `if(searchValue.equals(value))` compares a `String` (`searchValue`) with a `String[]` (`value`) hence will always be false.

Also, it would be better to covert the array into a list after splitting to utilise its `contains` method:

```
List<String> source = Arrays.asList(data.split(","));
if(source.contains(searchValue)){ /* write the logic to print the row */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out.

```
public class Test {

public static List<String[]> readData() throws IOException {
    String searchTerm = "LC1506";
    int count = 0;
    String file = "bos-2016-reg-csv-tables.csv";
    List<String[]> content = new ArrayList<>();
    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            content.add(line.split(","));
        }

        for (String[] aContent : content) {
            for (String value : aContent) {
                if(value.equals(searchTerm)) {
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(aContent));
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return content;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {
        readData();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}}
```